# ionic 2 reference in the page's code a component from dynamic array

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular2-template

I've a *slides* populated with `*ngFor` containing an array of instances of the same custom component (a canvas used like img), I need, in the `.ts` of the page using this *slides*, to access the current selected component and call some of its methods, something like:

```
let curr: MyComponent = this.slides[selected];
```

Notice that the array may change, so can't be something static on constructors/init.

I know how to use `#reference`, `ElementRef` and `@ViewChild` on one element, but I can't figure out the syntax to access one element in an array.

**edit**

I made an example with plunker but I'm not registered and don't know how long [the link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mRySocvhBcUcL6oIUkBI) will persists, so here below the modified sources from an angular2+typescript plunker project (sorry I realize only now this is a angular2 only question, not ionic)

So, what I would need is, from `App.current()` implementation access element instance `i` as `MyCoolComponent`

```
let curr: MyCoolComponent = ?
```

`src/app.ts`:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {MyCoolComponent} from './MyCoolComponent'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div *ngFor="let item of texts; let i = index">
        <my-cool text="{{item.text}}" (click)="current(i)"></my-cool>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  texts = [ 
    { text: "test1" },
    { text: "test2" },
    { text: "test3" }
  ]
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  current(i) {
    console.log('current: ',i)
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, MyCoolComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`src/MyCoolComponent.ts`:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cool',
  template: `
    cool {{text}}
  `,
})
export class MyCoolComponent {
  @Input('text') text:String;
  constructor() {
    this.text = `test`
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `selected`? Is it already a slide? Then you don't need to do anything?

Comment: @devqon `selected` is an integer index pointing the slide I want to access in the array. `this.slides[]` is only an example and is the part I can't figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are generally not to be injected into pages/other components. Thats what services are for. So you wont be able to "call" the functions of a component.

Your components aren't event handlers. If you have an event that needs to be handled, that should be encapsulated by the component its self, and if needed, emitted to its parent component/page.

Otherwise.. I would create an object holding the Component, and its ElementRef. Just update those values every time your array changes.

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented it with events, as you suggested emitting an event with the component instance as argument. Even being few changes I still think is an overhead, the component instances should be available in the template ngFor, a `(click)="dosomething($selfComponent)"` would have been enough. Cheers